# I can't beat the fish thing

Tags: psychonauts

I've got up to (I hope) the final stage in this boss fight, but none of my attacks affect it now. What should I do?

[image: This fish thing]

Comment: When you beat this boss, get ready for a level that has some of the best dialogue ever written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't attack the boss directly, but if you attack the yellow crates when he
breathes in, you will cause him to swallow bones and take damage that way.

Once you hit him about 4 times this way, the perspective changes and you get a
first-person view of the lungfish chasing you.  Basically you want to avoid or
attack the enemies and keep moving while you stay away from the outer wall that
separates you from the water.

Double-jump across the platforms and punch down some clear walls, then jump up
some large steps and run up some small ones.  Swing on some bars next to keep
climbing, then use levitate to bounce to the next ledge.  Run up the stairs and
keep following the path to begin the next part of the battle.

The tactics are the same in this part, but sometimes the boss blows out air
instead of inhaling it.  So ignore the yellow boxes when this happens, and only
break them when he inhales.

After about 3 more hits it's time for more running.  Your first obstacle is
some boxes to jump over and a beam to slide down, then you want to do a
double-jump to some netting up ahead and bounce with levitation to a higher
ledge.

Ignore the stairs and double-jump up the platforms instead, then smash the
doors in your way and grind down the beam [or just drop to the ground] as the
next part of the battle begins.

For this part of the battle you want to keep your distance and try not to step
on any sucker fish.  Otherwise you should get behind one of the clams and close
enough to touch it, this way the boss should get stuck on the clam when he
tries to attack you.

Once this happens you can get in close and score 3 quick punches before he
breaks free.  Once you connect with about 9 punches, the battle is finally
over.

Source: [Psychonauts Walkthrough - IGN FAQ's](http://uk.faqs.ign.com/articles/624/624690p1.html)

Answer (score 7):

With a bit more trying I found out that you have to get the antenna caught in one of the clams by getting him to swing it near them, you can then hit him as normal.

Comment: You have to stand slightly *before* the clam for this to work. Maybe even a bit to the right. I was trying to get him to step on it by standing *behind* the clam, which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get him to swing his glowing thing into the clams

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything new that isn't covered in other answers. Do you have anything new to add?